# What is the term for making one UI component better but is not in sync with whole of UI?

Tags: gui-design, user-research, design-process

Individual UI component owners (developer/GD) tries to make their component more useable/shining in the process losing the focus in the overall picture. I have somewhere read this to be something like "gold fingering", where individual sculptures were working on a clay model on their own part to form big structure. One guy was supposed to make a finger and he made a golden finger so the term. But if somebody can tell me what is the general term for addressing such thing in software? Also let me know if this is not the forum to address this question where to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I know this process is called **Gold plating**!

> Gold plating in software engineering or Project Management (or time management in general) refers to continuing to work on a project or task well past the point where the extra effort is worth the value it adds (if any). After having met the requirements, the developer works on further enhancing the product, thinking the customer would be delighted to see additional or **more polished features**, rather than what was asked for or expected. The customer might be disappointed in the results, and the extra effort by the developer might be futile.

Reference: [Wikipedia - Gold plating (software engineering)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating_%28software_engineering%29)